# Fuzzywuzzy import error weirdness

Tags: python, import, fuzzywuzzy

I have installed fuzzywuzzy via pip install into a virtual environment [fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1].

In the python interpreter (via ipython) I do the following

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

a = "my name is lena"
b = "my name is Elena"

fuzz.ratio(a,b)
```

Which works fine and gives me a result.

Next, I write the following into a file (using Sublime Text):

```
#!/Users/InNov8/Projects/datamine/denv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

'''
Fuzzy Logic Test
'''
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

a = "my name is lena"
b = "my name is Elena"

print fuzz.ratio(a,b)
```

When I run this in terminal I get the following error:

File "/Users/InNov8/Projects/datamine/_MiningScripts/fuzz-test2.py", line 4, in 
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
ImportError: No module named fuzzywuzzy

Is there any reason why a module does import successfully into the interpreter, but wouldn't import when executed from a script?

I am using the same version of python in both, i.e, via the virtualenv

```
#!/Users/InNov8/Projects/datamine/denv/bin/python
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is your virtualenv activated when you try to run the script?

Comment: Yes. I do the following, cd to the directory, then "source denv/bin/activate" where denv is the name of the virtual env. The "she-bang" (?) line in the code points to the same python in the virtual env.

Comment: have you installed it in your virtualenv ?

Comment: In your activated virtualenv, type pip freeze to see if the package shows up in the list of installed packages.

Comment: Yes it does --     (denv)Manishs-MacBook-Pro:datamine InNov8$ pip freeze
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
MechanicalSoup==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==2.2.0
pygoogle==0.6
requests==2.3.0
six==1.7.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
xgoogle==1.3
xlrd==0.9.3
xlwt==0.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, somehow changing the shebang to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

makes it work properly now...  Can't explain it, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall fuzzywuzzy Library again.

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
pip3 install fuzzywuzzy
```